# A type literal property cannot have an initializer in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my class in title gives me an error of

> "A type literal property cannot have an initializer"

If I remove `title` its working fine, I'm using `Angular 4.3.1`

```
export class MyClass{
    data:[
      {
        blood:string;
        title:string = 'Blood Pressure - Systolic (mm/Hg)';
      }
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your object you can't specify the type for properties when you also have value for them.

In this case you haven't specified the object, but it's type. I think you can create an interface (`shape)` for your array's items and use that for strong type.

```
interface Item {
   blood: string,
   title: string
}

export class MyClass{
    data: Item[] = [];
}
```

Here your array holds items with the `shape` `Item`. And you can push data into it which corresponds to the shape of the items.

```
data.push({
    blood: 'B (III) Rh (+)',
    title: 'Blood Pressure - Systolic (mm/Hg)'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are trying to make an object directly instead of a class. Or you are trying to make a class in which some variables have default values. A better approach for the same would look like:

```
export class SomeClass {
param1: string[]; 
param2: string; 

constructor(param1?: string[],
            param2?: string) {

    this.param1 = param1 || [];
    this.param2 = param2 || '';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for the object you are trying to create.

```
export class MyData {
    blood: string;
    title: string;
}
```

In your other class, you can now use it.

```
export class MyClass{
    data: MyData[] = [];
    data.push({
        blood: 'foo',
        title: 'Blood Pressure - Systolic (mm/Hg)'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface to define the data types:

```
interface IInterface {
   blood: string,
   title: string
}

export class MyClass {
    data: IInterface[] = [];
}
```

or you change the way you were doing it to:

```
export class MyClass {
    data:[
      {
        blood: string;
        title: string;
      }
    ];
}
```